# Why do people use this expression?

Tags: expressions

Lets say someone states "Tom runs fast, *how* fast is another question."

Why do and can people say 'is another question' even if there is no previous question explicitly stated?

Comment: The reference is to the ***implied, but not actually asked*** question ***Does Tom run fast**?* Similar to *Tom speaks French fluently, but his German is **a whole 'nother ball-game***, except with *that* example you'd struggle to explicitly identify the "implicit ball-game" being contrasted with ***another** one*).

Comment: I suspected that that is the case but what is the point of saying it then?

Comment: It’s so that the speaker can subtly imply that they have some doubts as to how far their previous statement might actually extend.

Answer (score 2):

The sense is "That is the answer to the question you asked (or implied), but the question you *should* have asked - the more important question - is something else".

Answer (score 2):

Because the word [question](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/question) has several meanings.  The most common meaning is

> 1. a sentence in an interrogative form, addressed to someone in order to get information in reply.

But there are other meanings, including:

> 2. a problem for discussion or under discussion; a matter for investigation.
> 3. a subject of dispute or controversy.

So, it is disputed exactly how fast he runs, it is a matter for debate, discussion or investigation. It is perfectly correct to say it is a question, in this sense.